# Size of data type using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

In NumPy, I can get the size (in bytes) of a particular data type by:

```
datatype(...).itemsize
```

or:

```
datatype(...).nbytes
```

For example:

```
np.float32(5).itemsize # 4
np.float32(5).nbytes   # 4
```

I have two questions. First, is there a way to get this information *without creating an instance* of the datatype? Second, what's the difference between `itemsize` and `nbytes`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need an instance of the `dtype` to get the itemsize, but you shouldn't need an instance of the `ndarray`.  (As will become clear in a second, `nbytes` is a property of the array, not the dtype.)

E.g.

```
print np.dtype(float).itemsize
print np.dtype(np.float32).itemsize
print np.dtype('|S10').itemsize
```

As far as the difference between `itemsize` and `nbytes`, `nbytes` is just `x.itemsize * x.size`.

E.g.

```
In [16]: print np.arange(100).itemsize
8

In [17]: print np.arange(100).nbytes
800
```

Comment: Good answer.  In fact, I'm not using an array at this point.  In my real use-case, I have a datafile format that is record based -- It has a header with 240 bytes and then the data.  The size of the data is determined by the number of elements (which is read from the header) but the data-type isn't stored :-(.  Ultimately, I want the user to be able to pass `dtype=...` and from that datatype, I'd get the sizeof each data element and so I can know the size of the data.  That way, I can seek to any record in the file and read it directly.  It looks like `np.dtype` is the way to go... thanks.

Comment: FWIW, It seems confusing that `nbytes` would be an instance of the data type when it is really only particularly useful in an array ... Of course, I suppose that I don't know the numpy data model well enough to comment on that too much ... Anyway, Thanks.  This is what I needed.

Comment: I agree, numpy's scalars (e.g. `np.float32(5)`) can be confusing.  The difference between a numpy scalar and a 0-d numpy array (e.g. `np.array(5, dtype=np.float32)`) is even more confusing. (Try indexing the 0-d array!)  The reason numpy scalars exist and have the same attributes as a normal ndarray is so things like `x[5].abs()` will work correctly for 1d arrays.  It makes sense in the "broader picture" but it causes a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the NumPy C source file, this is the comment:

```
size : int
    Number of elements in the array.
itemsize : int
    The memory use of each array element in bytes.
nbytes : int
    The total number of bytes required to store the array data,
    i.e., ``itemsize * size``.
```

So in NumPy:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((3, 5, 2), dtype=np.float64)
>>> x.itemsize
8
```

So `.nbytes` is a shortcut for:

```
>>> np.prod(x.shape)*x.itemsize
240
>>> x.nbytes
240
```

So, to get a base size of a NumPy array without creating an instance of it, you can do this (assuming a 3x5x2 array of doubles for example):

```
>>> np.float64(1).itemsize * np.prod([3,5,2])
240
```

However, important note from the NumPy help file:

```
|  nbytes
|      Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array.
|
|      Notes
|      -----
|      Does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the
|      array object.
```

Comment: You created an instance via `np.float64(1)` which is what I was trying to avoid.  The reason I wanted to avoid it is because when reading that line, a user might say "why 1?" ... when in fact, 1 isn't special ... It's just that I need an instance of `np.float64` to get the itemsize ... However, +1 for answering the second question about itemsize vs nbytes (and reading the source)...

Comment: You can do `np.float64().itemsize` as well. However, if you time the alternatives `np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize` is a bit faster than `np.float64().itemsize` Not so much to matter, but enough. It boils down to what you consider more readable I suppose.

Comment: Interesting ... Thanks for pointing out that `np.float64()` works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.iinfo` for ints and `np.finfo` for floats. Then, use the `.bits` attribute, and divide by 8 to get number of bytes. No need to create an instance of the datatype, as per the question.

For example:

```
np.iinfo(np.int32).bits // 8      # 4  
np.finfo(np.float16).bits // 8    # 2
```