# easy way of getting number of bits from a numpy type?

Tags: python, types, numpy

Is there an easy way to get the number of 8-bit bytes that corresponds to a particular numpy type?

I know I can do this:

```
lookup = {np.uint8:   1, np.int8:   1,
          np.uint16:  2, np.int16:  2, 
          np.uint32:  4, np.int32:  4,
          np.uint64:  8, np.int64:  8}
def getByteSize(dtype):
   return lookup[dtype]
```

but this seems slightly kludgey and it seems like there ought to be a built-in method of retrieving this info.

Comment: Use `np.iinfo` for ints and `np.finfo` for floats. Then, use the `.bits` attribute, and divide by 8 to get number of bytes. No need to create an instance of the datatype.

For example: 

    `np.iinfo(np.int32).bits // 8      # 4`       
or with floats 
    `np.finfo(np.float16).bits // 8    # 2`

Comment: add this as answer?

Comment: this question is closed as it is duplicated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972501/size-of-data-type-using-numpy - so answers can't be added here. I did post this answer there as an answer, it was only posted recently so you will find it languishing at the bottom of that page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `nbytes` attribute of an instance of the type:

```
In [8]: np.uint8(0).nbytes
Out[8]: 1

In [9]: np.uint16(0).nbytes
Out[9]: 2

In [10]: np.uint32(0).nbytes
Out[10]: 4
```

etc.

You can drop the argument (0 is assumed), and you can also use the `itemsize` attribute instead of `nbytes`:

```
In [13]: np.int32().itemsize
Out[13]: 4
```

A method that (apparently) avoids creating an instance of the numeric type is to create a `dtype` object, and then access its `itemsize` attribute (but I doubt this is going to be more memory or time efficient than simply creating an instance of the numeric type):

```
In [14]: dt = np.dtype(np.int32)

In [15]: dt.itemsize
Out[15]: 4
```

(I said "apparently" because I haven't looked at the source code for `dtype`.  For all I know, it might create an instance of its argument.)

Comment: is there any way without having to create an instance?

Comment: @JasonS: It seems like that *should* be possible, but I didn't find an obvious way to do that.  I've updated my answer with an alternative, but I don't think it is much better than creating an instance.