# Large Array of binary data

Tags: python

I'm working with a large 3 dimensional array of data that is binary, each value is one of two possible values. I currently have this data stored in the numpy array as int32 objects that are either 1 or 0.

It works fine for small arrays but eventually i will need to make the array 5000x5000x20, which I can't even get close to without getting "Memory Error".

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better way to do this? I am really hoping that I can keep it all together in one data structure because I will need to access slices of it along all three axes.

Comment: Why use 32 bits when you only need one? Try `int8`/`bool_` and you've got four times the space; see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: How much of the data is 1s and how much is 0s. If you have predominantly one or the other, you should consider using a sparse array data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get better performance if you change the datatype of your numpy array to something smaller.

For data which can take one of two values, you could use `uint8`, which will always be a single byte:

```
arr = np.array(your_data, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Alternatively, you could use `np.bool`, though I'm not sure offhand whether that is in fact a 8 bit value or whether it uses the native word size.  (I tend to explicitly use the 8 bit value for clarity, though that's more a personal choice.)

---

At the end of the day, though, you're talking about a *lot* of data, and it's quite possible that even with a smaller set of values, you won't be able to load it all into python at once.

In that case, it might be worth investigating whether you can break up your problem into smaller parts.

Comment: Per the doc link I posted above, the Boolean in numpy is a byte.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like using np.uint8 i'll be able to make an array large enought for my data. As a side question, what do you use to find the memory size of an object? I was using sys.getsizeof() and it said that np.uint8 and np.bool were both 12 bytes, the same as int32.

Comment: @user3927843 - You can use `.nbytes`, eg `np.uint8(1).nbytes`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972501/numpy-size-of-data-type  `sys.getsizeof` will return the size of the datatype object, rather than the size of the underlying data, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to represent the last axis of 20 bits as a single 32 bit integer. This way a 5000x5000 array would suffice.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it might make certain operations more difficult (as masking would be required).  Really depends how the OP uses the third dimension; it's the usual trade-off of space for time.