# How to append reshaped / flattened images to a python list without consuming too much memory?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, neural-network

I'm trying to read around 2,000 grayscale images (640 x 480) from a directory using opencv, scale down the intensity values between 0 and 1, flatten the images as one-dimensional numpy arrays and append them to a list for feeding them to a Neural Network later. This is my code :

```
import os
import cv2 as cv

path = "images/"
img_names = os.listdir(path)

x = []

for name in img_names:
    fullpath = path+name
    img = cv.imread(fullpath, 0).astype(float)
    img /= 255.0
    x.append(img.ravel())
```

When I try to execute this code, my memory usage goes up rapidly and then everything starts to lag and freeze. So, what really is going wrong here? Any suggestions on improving the process? It works fast and smooth for 100 images but not with over 1000 images.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Core i5 2.6 GHz laptop with 4 GB RAM.

Comment: 2000 images are going to be > 4GB in memory, so you will start using swap space which is dog slow. process them in batches or 1 at a time.

Comment: Are you really willing to feed a NN with 614400000 raw pixels ? You may have your reasons but this looks crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your images is 640 * 480, or 307200 pixels.  You're reading each pixel as as a `float`, [which might be as much as 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972501/numpy-size-of-data-type):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.dtype(float).itemsize 
8
>>>
```

So after 1000 images you're using at least around  8 * 307200 * 1000 = 2.3GB of RAM.  That's a conservative estimate.

Instead of trying to preload all of your images, how about using a generator to serve them one at a time?

```
def next_image():
    for name in img_names:
        fullpath = path+name
        img = cv.imread(fullpath, 0).astype(float)
        img /= 255.0
        yield img.ravel()
```

`next_image()` is now an iterable entity that generates the data on the fly. e.g.,

```
for image in next_image():
    feed(image)
```

Comment: Generators seem like the way to. Thanks!