# Get information about a numpy dtype

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement a validity check on a numpy type - specifically, if  `np.longdouble` is the 80-bit extended precision float - and get its raw byte size (with padding).

Accoring to [`dtype` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype), I can get a whole bunch of information from attributes. But, whichever attribute I check, I get

```
In [23]: np.longdouble.nbytes
Out[23]: <attribute 'nbytes' of 'numpy.generic' objects>
```

instead of the number.

I can get a whole bunch of information from `np.finfo(np.longdouble)` but it doesn't include byte size.

Sure, I can create an array of that type and calculate the size or something... but is this really necessary to get information that's not bound to a specific instance?

Comment: Would this help ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972501/numpy-size-of-data-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Numpy size of data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972501/numpy-size-of-data-type), `np.dtype(<type>)` is needed to actually get the real attribute values. Weird!

Here (using the [`dump`](https://github.com/native-api/dump) module):

```
In [27]: dump(np.dtype(np.longdouble))
alignment : 8
base : float64
byteorder : =
char : g
descr : [('', '<f8')]
fields : None
flags : 0
hasobject : False
isalignedstruct : False
isbuiltin : 1
isnative : True
itemsize : 8
kind : f
metadata : None
name : float64
names : None
num : 13
shape : ()
str : <f8
subdtype : None
type : <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

This output is from Python 2.7 on `win32` platform and, [predictably](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision), `np.longdouble` is double rather than extended precision here.

For comparison, here's an output from x86 CentOS 6 where it's extended:

```
alignment : 4
base : float96
byteorder : =
char : g
descr : [('', '<f12')]
fields : None
flags : 0
hasobject : False
isbuiltin : 1
isnative : True
itemsize : 12
kind : f
metadata : None
name : float96
names : None
num : 13
shape : ()
str : <f12
subdtype : None
type : <type 'numpy.float96'>
```

Comment: What version are you running?  OS?  I get an itemsize of 12 on my Linux 3.5+.

Comment: @hpaulj 2.7 on win32. The output is just an example - I don't want to clutter the answer with all possible outputs on all sorts of platforms. I've added a note to this effect. After all, the question is about just getting the values rather than all aspects of validating `np.longdouble` as 80-bit.

Comment: I'm writing an OpenCL program with pyopencl. Though according to [the document](http://man.opencl.org/scalarDataTypes.html) the `uint` type is always 4 bytes, I'd like to refer to the datatype size in a programmatic way. Therefore, I use `cl.cltypes.uint.nbytes` with resulting in a `<attribute 'nbytes' of 'numpy.generic' objects>`. However, whenever I try to `np.dtype(cl.cltypes.uint.nbytes)`, I get a `TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'nbytes' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type`. Any ideas?

Comment: @TJM `np.dtype(cl.cltypes.uint)`

Comment: the enlightening insight was that it is *not* `np.dtype(object)` as in the numpy documentation, but `np.dtype(type(object))`. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Going the instance route:

```
In [1586]: np.array(1,np.longdouble)
Out[1586]: array(1.0, dtype=float96)
In [1587]: np.longdouble(1).nbytes
Out[1587]: 12

In [1588]: np.dtype(np.longdouble)
Out[1588]: dtype('float96')
```

The default float is `float64`.

`nbytes` is the attribute of the instance, not attribute of the class.  That distinction is quite common in Python.

If I make a `dtype` object from it:

```
In [1592]: dt=np.dtype(np.longdouble)
In [1593]: dt
Out[1593]: dtype('float96')
In [1594]: dt.descr
Out[1594]: [('', '<f12')]
In [1595]: dt.itemsize
Out[1595]: 12
```

`np.typeDict` maps codes to types.  And type names often indicate the size.

```
In [1600]: np.typeDict['longdouble']
Out[1600]: numpy.float96
```

===================

`finfo` starts with `np.dtype(dtype)`.  So the `dt.itemsize` is the correct way to get the byte size of a type like this.

Since dtypes have a lot of synonyms, it makes sense to use a 'central clearing house' like `np.dtype`.  And there is some dependence on the compiler, so some attributes have to be derived at runtime, as opposed to being hard coded in some python class definition.

Comment: Note: `typeDict` is undocumented.

Comment: A `github` search doesn't show any documentation reference to it.  But it is created in `numpy/numpy/core/numerictypes.py`